# Tomcat 7 startup error: tcnative.dll is not valid

Tags: java, tomcat, intellij-idea

I use;

Windows 7 64 bit,
JAVA_HOME= JDK1.7 64 bit,
Tomcat-7 64 bit version

When I start tomcat from commandline it works ok, but when I use it within IntelliJ I get this error;

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: tcnative-1 (.\tcnative-1.dll is not a valid Win32 application.
```

I also point to an IBM 32bit JDK1.6 from IntelliJ in project settings, but this could not be a problem since this setup works on some other collegae's computers

I have read similar questions here, but none of them offers a solution for my case, any ideas, how can I fix this?

Comment: @The New Idiot tnx replacing the tcnative dll from the apache site solved problem, stil dont know though why the existing dll didn't work. I can accept thsi as an answer if you answer question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a [link](http://errorlist.blogspot.in/2009/08/javalangunsatisfiedlinkerror-no.html) which describes the problem :

**Cause:**

You get this message when you start Tomcat. Tomcat is looking for a shared object call *tcnative (dll or so depending on the platform)*. If it doesn't find it, it'll revert to java libs. Either way, this shouldn't affect your application. *tcnative dll* is needed to address scalability in Tomcat.

**Solution:**

1. Turn down debugging level for Tomcat or
2. Get tcnative from http://tomcat.apache.org/native-doc/ (windows users can download the binary) and place it in your library path.
3. Lib path is usually: C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation{Apache Tomcat directory}\lib; for windows

Answer (score 0):

Basically It seems that you may have an incorrect version.

Are you using multiple java on your machines if yes then try to look into environment variables for JAVA_HOME & PATH. Secondly, also paste the complete version of java and tomcat

Also run following commands at command prompt

java -version
javac -version
echo %JAVA_HOME%

And are you using MSI installer of tomcat or just a zip version of tomcat. Because in many cases MSI installer never work for some ghost reasons.